# Using a single .gitignore for multiple repositories

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a number of git repos that have the same overall development use, tooling, and file/folder structure.  The .gitignore is the same for each repo.  Is there a way to use a single .gitignore for all the repos to reduce the maintenance burden, rather than updating each individually?  I have maybe 3 styles of repositories, so 3 versions of common .gitignore files.

The only approach I can think of is to store the .gitignore files in their own repo, include the repo as a submodule in every repository that would use them, then create the top level .gitignore as a symlink to the desired version in the submodule.  This approach seems overly complex.

Comment: I'm not understanding what the problem is. Why not just use a single global `.gitignore`?

Comment: Global .gitignores are local to each user.  I want something stored in the repo, which everyone picks up when they clone the repo or if the repo is used as a submodule.

Comment: I thought you might say that. Yeah, then you'd need a config script that copies this gitignore into every repo.

Answer (score 1):

I see three solutions none of which is ideal. All of them are complex and require automation scripts.

### Solution number 1

A separate repository with `.gitignore` added as a submodule or subtree to all repositories (let call them "client repos" to distinguish from users that will clone the repos) and a symlink.

The advantage — a user cloned or pulled a client repo get `.gitignore` automatically.

The disadvantages are: 1) all users need to use operating systems that support symlinks; 2) after updating `.gitignore` you need to update and push all you repositories because with submodules the superproject (client repo) stores exact submodule's commit and subtree stores exact copy; so you need a script to update and push all your repositories.

### Solution number 2

Just add the `.gitignore` to all client repos as a file. Add, commit, push. On any update synchronize the file in all repositories using a script. Add, commit, push.

The advantage — a user cloned or pulled a client repo get `.gitignore` automatically. The disadvantage is: you need a script to update all your repositories.

### Solution number 3

Create a separate repository with `.gitignore` and a script that runs `git config core.excludesFile /path/to/.gitignore`.

The advantage — simple setup. The disadvantages are: 1) you need to write a script to update user's configuration; 2) teach all users to run the script and regularly update the separate `.gitignore` repo.

In my personal opinion Solution 2 is the simplest, well, least hard.