# Import common files from another project on GitLab

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I want to import the files that are shared in my two projects on gitlab from another project.
For example:

Common Project (includes `xxx.c`)
Project1 (includes `code1.c`, `code2.c` and `xxx.c`)
Project2 (includes code4.c, code3.c and `xxx.c`)

if I change the `xxx.c` in project 1, I want it to change in the common project, so it must have changed in project 2 as well. If it's possible how can i do it?

I expecting If it's possible how can i do it?

Comment: Some ideas about shared files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75959271/7976758